# Is my Java version 5?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have a program whose README says it requires Java 5 or higher. I check the version of Java on my Ubuntu:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.9) (6b20-1.9.9-0ubuntu1~10.10.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

I was wondering if 1.6.0_20 means Java 1.6.0_20, and therefore far older than Java 5? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java version numbers are weird. In some contexts they include an initial `1.`; others do not. But `1.6.0` is what people usually call "Java 6", so you should be okay here.

Back in the day, there was "Java 1.1", which had a version number of 1.1.x. However, when "Java2" was released it had a version number of 1.**2**.x, and it's been like that ever since.

Answer (score 6):

Java 1.6.x is Java 6.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6_.28December_11.2C_2006.29

Answer (score 5):

You've actually got Java 6 so you should be ok!

Java 1.**5**.x is Java 5; Java 1.**6**.x is Java 6.